# All jars of Spring for a given version

Tags: spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I downloaded jars of Spring framework for version 4.2.4 from site:

`http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/`

I am learning JdbcTemplate, and for one of the programs I wanted to use `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject`. And indirectly it needs spring-dao as well (Came to know by the error which Eclipse IDE displayed).

Now, in the jars downloaded from above link for version 4.2.4 I didn't find anything spring-dao. Then doing hit-and-trial I downloaded it from `http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao/2.0.3` the version being `2.0.3`.

Now I want to understand why spring-dao isn't included in the link supposedly to have all the jars? From where can I get this for a given version?

Comment: Please use a build tool like maven or gradle and avoid this approach

Comment: There is no spring-dao-4.2.4, instead I found version which is very old. My question is why spring-dao isn;t in the zip which is supposedly to have all the jars or is spring-dao part of some other distrubution.  For self learning,  I want to keep it simple and better off without using any build tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spring-dao is not used since 2008, the code from the package org.springframework.dao now resides inside spring-tx

so you need spring-tx, which is provided in http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.2.4.RELEASE/ (download the **dist** file)

see github for [spring-tx and dao package](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/dao)
and [maven central for spring-dao](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Indeed it fix the issue.